# Android action bar icons: core_discard vs core_remove

Tags: android, icons, styling

The [Iconography page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) has helped me a lot in learning how to use icons well in my apps. You can also download a set of standard icons to use in your apps from that page. I am currently making a messaging app. When long-clicking the custom input view, a popup menu appears. Each item on the menu uses one of the actionbar icons. One of my menu items is "Clear all text", but I don't know what icon to use for it.

I see in Android's core icon set there is a `discard` and a `remove`. Here is `ic_action_discard.png`:

[image]

And here is `ic_action_remove.png`:

[image]

I'm not asking which one you like better. (I actually might like to know, but that kind of question is not allowed on StackOverflow, right? so...) I want to know if the Android documents have any sort of description or styling guidelines that tell how the different icons should be used. I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: I haven't found any guidelines, so I usually use the ones I like. Just as a tip and kinda off-topic (but I mention it because you seem to be interested in following the Google guidelines), you may want to take a look at the new [Material Design Iconography Guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons) and use the new set of [System Icons](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-system-icons) :) you may notice that the trash can has changed, for example.

Comment: So helpful! This is something I need to study more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ic_action_remove.png
```

used to clear text in `EditText`

and

```
ic_action_discard.png
```

used to remove some / all item from our `Collection`

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any external references or is this just how you use it?